# subprocess.call не видит программу

Tags: python, subprocess

Хочу запустить несколько программ с помощью одного скрипта, но выдает ошибку, в чем проблема?

```
import os
from subprocess import call
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import sys

try:
    subprocess.call(['python3','C:/Users/К.Бояр (Второй)/source/repos/Rozetka_Parcer/Rozetka_Parcer/Rozetka_Parcer.py'])
except Exception as e:
    print ('Process failed',e)
try:
    subprocess.call(['python3','C:/Users/К.Бояр (Второй)/source/repos/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer/ALLOParcer.py'])
except Exception as e:
    print ('Process failed',e)
```

```
Process failed name 'subprocess' is not defined
Process failed name 'subprocess' is not defined
Поток 'MainThread' (0x1) завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
Программа "python.exe" завершилась с кодом 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут что-то одно. Либо импортируете саму **библиотеку** `subprocess` и обращаетесь к ней так, как вы это делаете, через имя библиотеки и потом уже имя функции через точку:

```
import subprocess

...
try:
    subprocess.call(...
```

Либо импортируете так, как вы это делаете, **конкретную функцию** `call` из библиотеки `subprocess`, но тогда и вызывать нужно именно эту конкретную функцию сразу по имени:

```
from subprocess import call

...
try:
    call(...
```

В вашем же случае, поскольку вы не импортировали саму библиотеку `subprocess`, питон не понимает, что такое `subprocess` у вас дальше в коде программы.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Спасибо большое, только вылезла другая небольшая проблема, пишет вот такое:
`Process failed [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл`

Из-за чего такое может быть? Я могу создать отдельный вопрос, если в этом есть нужда.

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII Для начала попробуйте к `python3` тоже полный путь указать при вызове функции `call`